# MATLAB time duration in milliseconds from an excel file

Tags: matlab

I am making a Matlab program that uses data from an excel file designated from an open file dialog.

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.xlsx','Excel Files(*.xlsx)'; '*.txt','Txt Files(*.txt)'}, 'Pick a file');
FilePath = append(pathname,filename);

opts = detectImportOptions(FilePath, "ReadVariableNames", false);
opts = setvartype(opts, 1, 'char');
data = readtable(FilePath, opts);

table = data(:,1);
```

Now the code is like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH2l1.png)
After that, as you see the date is saved as string.

But what I really want to find is time difference (duration) in milliseconds.

The raw data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9bms.png)

A column and C column has the same time, so I want to only use A column data.

Please help a newbie with this!! I appreciate!

Comment: try using the Home / Import Data tool to first attempt manual import, and then select "create function" to create an import function instead of importing the data. Looking at the code in the generated function should help you figure it out... If not please report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

I share my code to help other people suffering the same problem.

Please leave comments if things can be more simplified.

1. Importing an Excel file to analyze

```
% Clean the memory and the code previously running
clc;
clear all;
close all;

% Sampling frequency of the acquired data
fs = 1e2; % Sampling Frequency - this can be found on LabView code.
Ts = 1/fs; % Sampling Interval

%Importing data from an excel file
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.xlsx','Excel Files(*.xlsx)'; '*.txt','Txt Files(*.txt)'}, 'Pick a file');
FilePath = append(pathname,filename);

[fPath ,fName, fExt] = fileparts(FilePath);
```

a. To find "Time duration" from the file

```
opts = spreadsheetImportOptions("NumVariables", 1);

% Specify sheet and range
opts.Sheet = "sheet1";
opts.DataRange = "A2";

% Specify column names and types
opts.VariableNames = "Time";
opts.VariableTypes = "datetime";

% Specify file level properties
opts.ImportErrorRule = "omitrow";
opts.MissingRule = "omitrow";

% Specify variable properties
opts = setvaropts(opts, "Time", "InputFormat", 'mm:ss.SSS');

tTable = readtable(FilePath, opts, "UseExcel", false);
tArray = table2array(tTable);

% Calculating time duration
tArray = tArray - tArray(1);

% Coverting to seconds
time = milliseconds(tArray)*1e-3;

% Clear temporary variables
clear opts;

% Discarding data if time difference is too big
ii = size(time(:,1));
k = 0;
disp('Now removing error data elements');

for i = 1:1:ii(1)-1
    a = time(i);
    b = time(i+1);
    if (b-a)>0.5 && k==0
        k=i+1;
        
        fprintf('Elements from %d seconds will be removed. (%dth element)\n', time(k),k);
        
        for j = ii(1):-1:k
            
            if rem(j,10)==0
                fprintf('%dth element is removed... \n',j);
            end
            
            time(j) = [];
        end
        
        break % Break the loop after removing error data
    end
end

disp('Time table is set.');

clearvars -except filename FilePath fs pathname time k ii Ts fName
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar excel file and I found the time columns are read as a char. So, what I did is get the index of those columns and convert it to datatime. After that, looks that it is working. Hopefully, this works.

```
% Define the excel file name (can be the path)
ExcelFile = 'demo_stackflow.xlsx';

% Get the options for that sheet and preserving the variable name
opts = detectImportOptions(ExcelFile,'Sheet','Sheet1',...
    "VariableNamingRule","preserve")
% Get the idx where the variable is a char (In this case col 1 and 3)
CharVars = opts.VariableNames(contains(opts.VariableTypes,'char'));
% Convert the char columns to datetime
opts = setvaropts(opts,CharVars,'Type',"datetime");
% Get the data
data = readtable(ExcelFile, opts)
% Print the 1st column to see if the data type of the column is
%  datetime
T = data(:,1)
```

Comment: this does not work. but thank you for your time!
Error using detectImportOptions (line 381)
All parameters must have an associated value.

Comment: Can you share the error message? maybe I am assuming a certain data type in my "example".

Comment: I solved the problem. I will post my code